# How to send query to telegrambot by clicking a link, not a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I built a telegrambot in Python. I managed to send a keyboard with a message (allowing me to send callback queries to the bot) using [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py) example.
Now, if I only have one option, these buttons are a bit large in my opinion which is why I'd like to find another solution to send a callback query to the bot. Is there a way to send such a query by clicking a link inside a message? From the [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), I don't see an obvious way to do that.

**To provide more context:** I built a command `/reminder` to schedule and send reminders (as Telegram messages, see attached screenshot).
When a reminder is scheduled, the bot will send a message saying that the reminder was scheduled. In this message, I'd like to append a link "Delete" in the text (not as `InlineKeyboardButton`, because such a button would make this "FYI, I scheduled the reminder, just as you requested" message too large in my opinion) and clicking this link shall send a query to the bot which I then can use to remove the correct reminder from the jobqueue and database.
The last message in the screenshot (when the reminder is actually sent and can be rescheduled via buttons) is only to show that the buttons indeed significantly increase the vertical space of such a message.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add MessageHandler to list of handlers.

```py
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, some_handler_method)])
```

So update from buttons will go to `CallbackQueryHandler` and typed text to `MessageHandler`.